# Match Rails end_of_month to Time with the same data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to write an assertion on a class that depends on Rails' `end_of_month`, but I can't get it to equal a newly-created `Time` object:

```
Time.new(2014, 12).end_of_month == Time.new(2014, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59)
=> false
```

Both values return the same result from `to_i`:

```
Time.new(2014, 12).end_of_month.to_i
=> 1420030799
Time.new(2014, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59).to_i
=> 1420030799
```

But with `to_f` the result is slightly different:

```
Time.new(2014, 12).end_of_month.to_f
=> 1420030800.0
Time.new(2014, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59).to_f
=> 1420030799.0
```

Both objects report their class as `Time`. What's going on here? How can I create a `Time` object that will match what's returned by `end_of_month`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

float value is not accurate

you can tell the different by output rational value

```
Time.new(2014, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59).to_r
# => (1420041599/1)

Time.new(2014, 12).end_of_month.to_r
# => (1420041599999999999/1000000000)
```

From Time.to_f document

> Note that IEEE 754 double is not accurate enough to represent the
>   number of nanoseconds since the Epoch.

From Time.to_r document

> This methods is intended to be used to get an accurate value
>   representing the nanoseconds since the Epoch. You can use this method
>   to convert time to another Epoch.

When compare time, I usually use `to_i`, or `to_f` with rspec asset `be_within(0.01).of(27.9)`